# How to integrate my app to a larger app - iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, shared-libraries

We developed an app with multiple screens and resources (images). 
We would like to distribute this app as a component to be integrated to our client's app, in particular one module of the larger client app will be our app. Is there any way we can distribute it as a binary/library and not sharing the whole source code? 
The static library examples I have seen mostly consist of code only (single screen) and not with resource files and multiple screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package it as a framework. The framework would contain the compiled code, header files, and any resources (images, etc.). No source code would be needed.

Comment: Does framework support multiple screens and navigation between them?And any tutorial on framework is there? Thanks

Comment: A framework is just a fancy way to package your code for use in other apps. The packaged code can do whatever you can normally do. If the framework code includes a bunch of view controllers then the app using the framework can display those view controllers, no matter how many screens it is.  You can add a new target to your project. Setup the target to be a framework. There is plenty of info on this in the standard docs that come with the iOS SDK.